# Seconds to gmt and from gmt back to seconds in python using 'time' library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, time, gmt

For the following code, I expect the seconds_input and seconds_output, to be the same.
But I get an hour difference:

```
import time

seconds_input = 1571875186
date_struct1 = time.gmtime(seconds_input)

tm_str = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", date_struct1)
date_struct2 = time.strptime(tm_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
seconds_output = time.mktime(date_struct2)

print(seconds_input - seconds_output)
print(date_struct1, date_struct2)
```

I assume it could be due to `tm_isdst=-1` in the `date_struct2`, but I'm not sure how to set it to `0`.

I have tried the `date_struct2.tm_isdst = 0`, but got the following error:

```
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

**Update:**

if the seconds_input corresponds to the date in the future, then the seconds_input and seconds_output would be the same.

For example if seconds_input = 1673084786.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case (GMT+9) I have got 9 hours difference.

So I suppose you get the difference between your own TZ and GMT -- just as it should be.

To convert properly you have to add (or subtract) 3600sec, which is 1 hour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done it before and it wouldn't work if the time (seconds_input) corresponds to the date in the future. For example if seconds_input = 1673084786.